# Does it make sense to use django and npm in the same project?

Tags: django, web, npm, sass

I'm learning Django, I'm using Bootstrap etc. but I want to customize my website ui more.
I keep searching and I saw that, if I want to customize bootstrap I should use bootstap-sass downloaded with npm.

Well, my question is "Does it make sense to use django and npm in the same project?" or "Should I use a different method?"

Comment: Django is technology for the backend, you can use Javascript as technology for the frontend and thus use npm as a package manager for that: https://www.impressivewebs.com/npm-for-beginners-a-guide-for-front-end-developers/

Comment: Oh got it. I'm not flawed in any sense of that time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally makes sense. There are projects that are build this way - like [edx.org](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform) - django as the backend and some js framework as the frontend.

You can also customize and build bootstrap separately and use the output files in your Django project. This approach is easier.